# how to pass parameters from java to a python script?

Tags: java, python, parameters

I am begainer to python and I want to execute a python file in my java program. I have read many articls about how to pass parameters to a function in a python file. But this python program is designed to take parameters from a command line, like " ./a.py abc.txt", I have tried some method like

```
interp.execfile("d:/a.py abc.txt");
```

this method failed with "Exception in thread "main" IOError: (2, 'File not found - d:\a.py abc.txt....."

and

```
interp.exec("sys.arg[1]='abc.txt'");
interp.execfile("d:/a.py");
```

this method failed with
"Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):

File "string" line 1, in module

AttributeError: 'reflected field public org.python.core.PyObject o' object has no attribute 'arg'

All of those methods failed.

Comment: How is it not working ? Do you get any errors ? A little more information would be helpfull here.

Comment: How do you **use** the parameters? I guess your problem (that you don't describe at all) is that they are missing in your Python application?

Comment: @Torxed this python program take a file name in the command line and transfer it into another file type. like txt to pdf. what I am asking is how to pass the file name to the python script from the java program who invokes this script.

Comment: @user2293042 yes i figured that out, but **what is your issue**, can you describe what's **not** happening that you would like to happen? can't you see the filename at all? doesn't the python script run at all? what **doesn't happen**?

Comment: First, can you post some code as to how you are calling out to this Python app.  Second, can you post any errors you are getting.  I think what @Torxed is getting at is that your python path is probably wrong, but without the full code block we can't a) see if you are reading STDERR to properly get the error messages, and b) are doing something else that might be effecting the call out to python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("./a.py abc.txt");
```

Comment: Isn't ProcessBuilder the preferred way to execute external programs now?